# Put a main function args inside the thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

I'm having a problem with threads in java .
 This is my class that implements thread :

```
public class SensorAddClient extends Thread implements Runnable {
String[] args = new String[3];
@Override
public void run(){
try {
    SensorClient.main(args);//this is the main function i wanna get executed on my args
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

then i use the next 2 following lines to call it when i need to activate the thread:

`SensorAddClient cl = new SensorAddClient();
cl.start();`

I have to start a thread whose  run just has to call a specific class which executes using the args, so i call the main function of the class,is there any way to make the main function of the class i call to get executed with the args i want?
So ho can i put elements on that : 
String[] args = new String[3];  before executing the run of the thread? Is that possible ?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question, what exactly are you having and issue with? Do you want to pass arguments to your runnable?

Comment: Are you trying to run your entry point (`public static main`) in a Thread?

Comment: @user1875195 Im sorry if its  not  well explaned. What i was trying to say is that when i start the thread i want it to give me the possibility  to add values on that stringarray i call args, so the SensorClient 's main i call on the run method gets those args i choose. But i dont wanna use system.in.

Comment: @giannisf well im trying to run the main  of a class through a thread but i want it to run with the params i wanna pur. Coz actually when i run the SENSORCLIENT class i put the params from the console

Comment: @Anja.M Where are starting the thread?

Comment: @giannisf im starting it in another class.  None  of this

Comment: @Anja.M So what values do you want to pass to args? Your own or from the console?

Comment: @giannisf my own args

Comment: @Anja.M I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a constructor and add the values there:

```
public class SensorAddClient extends Thread implements Runnable {
String[] args = new String[3];

public SensorAddClient(String[] args) {

 this.args = args;

}
@Override
public void run(){
try {
    SensorClient.main(args);//this is the main function i wanna get executed on my args
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Comment: Well yea but its a bit more complicated coz the args i wanna put  are variables saved on that third class where i start the thread. I dont know of im explaining it right

Comment: @pass the arguments in the construct, I changed the answer

Comment: @Anja.M You are welcome. Please read a tutorial about OOP/Java, because constructors are very basic.